# How to make to read vectors with inputs/outputs in shiny?

Tags: r, variables, input, shiny, selectinput

I´m making a shiny app using lineal regression. I have a problem with inputs/outputs function, so I use SelectInput because I wand to the user can choose de variable to compare. But the trouble is that the input/output don´t take the values what came from a csv file. How can I solve it?

The code is:

```
datos <- read.csv("C:/Users/jerez/OneDrive/Escritorio/UAL/Datos1.csv", sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Analisis de Regresion"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    #Eleccion de variable x
    p("Selecciona la primera variable a comparar"),
    selectInput(inputId = "varX", label = "Variable eje X", multiple = FALSE, choices = list("NumBusquedas", "FrecuenciaAsistente", "FrecuenciasCorreos", "NumMensajes", "FreqDiscover", "NumUsosApp", "NumPublicidad","NumSuscripciones","NumBusquedasYoutube")),
    #Eleccion de variable y
    p("Selecciona la segunda variable a comparar"),
    selectInput(inputId = "varY", label = "Variable eje Y", multiple = FALSE, choices = list("NumBusquedas", "FrecuenciaAsistente", "FrecuenciasCorreos", "NumMensajes", "FreqDiscover", "NumUsosApp", "NumPublicidad","NumSuscripciones","NumBusquedasYoutube"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    #verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Datos"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "X"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Y"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "coefCorr"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "Grafico")
    
   
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$coefCorr <- renderPrint(cor(input$varX, input$varY))
  output$Grafico <- renderPlot(ggplot(datos, aes(input$varX, input$varY)))
  output$X <- renderPrint({input$varX})
  output$Y <- renderPrint({input$varY})
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikHmt.png)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `input$*` variables are `character`, not the numbers you think they are. Use `datos[[input$*]]`.
2. Similarly for `ggplot`; the preferred *programmatic* way to specify aesthetics is via `.data[[ input$* ]]` instead. (I previously suggested that `aes_string` was preferred, it is [deprecated](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html). Thanks to @starja for helping me to see that.)

**How to figure this out** the next time you get in this bind: insert `browser()` somewhere towards the beginning of a block that is causing problems. (An alternative is to use a technique I've included on the bottom of this answer.) For now, I'll choose:

```r
  output$coefCorr <- renderPrint({
    browser()
    cor(input$varX, input$var)
  })
```

(Since I don't have your data, I'll start with `datos <- mtcars`, and change both  select inputs to `choices=names(datos)`.)

When you run that app, it should immediately drop into a debugger on your console, waiting to execute the next line of code (`cor(...)`). As luck would have it, we're inside a `renderPrint` which will [`sink(.)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) all of the output. While this is by design, we will get zero interaction on the console until we stop the `sink`ing. To do that, `sink(NULL)` stops it.

```r
sink(NULL)
input$varX
# [1] "mpg"
input$varY
# [1] "mpg"
cor("mpg", "mpg")
# Error in cor("mpg", "mpg") : 'x' must be numeric
```

Does it make sense to run `cor`relation on two strings? What you likely need is `datos[[input$varX]]`:

```r
cor(datos[[input$varX]], datos[[input$varY]])
# [1] 1
```

Of course this is perfect "1", both are the same variable this time. For the sake of demonstration, I'll back out of the debugger, change the Y variable to `"disp"`, then re-enter the debugger:

```r
cor(datos[[input$varX]], datos[[input$varY]])
# [1] -0.8475514
```

That resolves the `numeric` error.

Once you get to the point of trying to plot, though, you'll see that you have another problem. (I'm continuing in the current debugger within `renderPrint`, just because it's convenient.) I'll add `geom_point()` so that there is something to show.

```r
ggplot(datos, aes(input$varX, input$varY)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot, single categorical point]

That is just a single point. Both axes are categorical variables with the value `"mpg"` and `"disp"`. In this case, we're up against `ggplot2`'s non-standard evaluation with `aes()`. Instead, tell ggplot that you're giving it *strings*, with

```r
ggplot(datos, aes(.data[[ input$varX ]], .data[[ input$varY ]])) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot, fixed]

Bottom line, this is what those two server blocks should look like:

```r
  output$coefCorr <- renderPrint({ cor(datos[[input$varX]], datos[[input$varY]]) })
  output$Grafico <- renderPlot(ggplot(datos, aes(.data[[ input$varX ]], .data[[ input$varY ]])) + geom_point())
```

(I'm still inferring `geom_point`, though again that's just for demonstration.)

---

**Side note:** when learning and developing shiny apps, I often insert a button and `observe` solely to give me direct access, not within a `render` block. For instance,

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Analisis de Regresion"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("debug", "DEBUG!"),
    # ...
  ),
  mainPanel(
    # ...
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$debug, { req(input$debug); browser(); 1; })
  # ...
}
```

When you run into a problem and don't want to stop the shiny app just to insert `browser()` and re-run it, just press the button.

(This should not be deployed to a shiny server, it is only relevant in local mode. In fact, I believe that attempts to deploy an app with `browser()` should trigger a warning if not more. Either way, don't try to use the debug button on a remote server :-)

Comment: Great explanation, just a comment on `aes_string`. It is soft-deprecated and now it's recommend to use `.data[[input$*]]` instead, see e.g. [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't heard yet that `aes_string` is deprecated, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you! You help me a lot with this! I´m new at that jejeje. You explain very well. Thank you again! :)